# Each result on a new line XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery, zorba

I know there is similar question asked but the solution given in that did not solve my issue. And since I have less reputation I am unable to comment on the same question page.

My XQuery code:

```
 <results>
    {
        for $p in
        (
        for $o in doc("mondial-3.0.xml") /mondial/organization
        where fn:count($o/members)
        order by fn:count($o/members) descending
        let $m := $o/members
        return <organization>
                <name> {$o/@name/string()} </name>
                <abbreviation> {$o/@abbrev/string()} </abbreviation>
                <num_members> {fn:count($o/members)} </num_members> 
                <country> {doc("mondial-3.0.xml")/mondial/country[@id=$m/@country]/@name/string()} </country>
           </organization>
        )[position() < 3]
        return $p
    }
    </results>
```

I am using Zorba as the XQuery engine for getting the output. The output which i am getting is correct, just that structure of my output is not the way I want it to be.

Currently all the countries are getting printed on the same line.

```
<country> Angola Argentina Bolivia.... </country>
```

But I want each new country to be on a new separate line.

```
<country> Angola </country>
<country> Argentina</country>
<country> Bolivia </country>
```

XML file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kroell/hsrm-mi-2semester-markuplanguage/master/Abgabe2/Aufgabe2/mondial-3.0.xml

Comment: My best guess, given that the current query is working as you said : `{for $m in $o/members return <country> {doc("mondial-3.0.xml")/mondial/country[@id=$m/@country]/@name/string()} </country>}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide example input, I could not provide a verified solution.

The issue is that you create one element containing text nodes for all country names. Create multiple text nodes instead, for example using another flwor expression:

```
<organization>
  <name> {$o/@name/string()} </name>
  <abbreviation> {$o/@abbrev/string()} </abbreviation>
  <num_members> {fn:count($o/members)} </num_members>
  {
    for $country in doc("mondial-3.0.xml")/mondial/country[@id=$m/@country]/@name/string()
    return <country>{ $country }</country>
  }
</organization>
```

If you've got support for XQuery 3.0, you can also go for element constructors in axis steps, having a more concise, implicit loop construction:

```
<organization>
  <name> {$o/@name/string()} </name>
  <abbreviation> {$o/@abbrev/string()} </abbreviation>
  <num_members> {fn:count($o/members)} </num_members>
  {
    doc("mondial-3.0.xml")/mondial/country[@id=$m/@country]/@name/element country { data() }
  }
</organization>
```

One recommendation: Instead of `<name> {$o/@name/string()} </name>`, better go for `<name>{ $o/@name/string() }</name>` to prevent superfluous whitespace around the information inside the tag.

Comment: The link to the XML file contains the sample input. The solution worked well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using another XQuery 3.0 feature, the simple map operator:

```
{ 
    doc("mondial-3.0.xml")/mondial/country[@id=$m/@country] ! <country>{ ./@name/string() }</country> 
}
```

This is the equivalent of the plain old FLWOR in XQuery 1.0:

```
{
    for $country in doc("mondial-3.0.xml")/mondial/country[@id=$m/@country]
    return
        <country>{ $country/@name/string() }</country>
}
```